# AngularJS passing result of custom filter to another custom filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created two custom filters and try to use both in ng-repeat.

How can i pass result of first filter as a input for second filter?

I tried as(alias) in ng-repeat but it not works,

```
<input type="text" ng-model = "ageLimit" />
<input type="text" ng-model = "lastSeen" />
<div ng-repeat = "member in lists | ageFilter:ageLimit:lists as results | LastSeenFilter:lastSeen:results">
```

Error message

Error: [ngRepeat:badident] alias ' results | LastSeenFilter:lastSeen:results' is invalid --- must be a valid JS identifier which is not a reserved name.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/ngRepeat/badident?p0=results%20%7C%20LastSeenFilter%3AselectLastSeen%3Aresults

Comment: Simply chaining/piping the two filters should to it, no? `member in lists | ageFilter:ageLimit | LastSeenFilter:lastSeen`

Comment: Its not working, chaining works for first time but when i change params to filter it apply to previous result(it apply filter in first filtered set not the whole set)

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in the "***as***". since i have the same problem i looked inside the ngRepeadDirective and found out that the regex there that breaks the expression does not support filters after alias as can be seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/aZ1cM8/1).

Comment: Don't you have solution for it? I need first filter for paging (total records, so on), and second filter to display.

Comment: no, there is no solution for that, but for paging there is are great solution and directives such as http://brantwills.github.io/Angular-Paging/ , and you can google for more, pagination is just a thing to learn and its easy

Comment: Yeah, I know, just want to try new way. I've already changed to another way for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can chain filters in Angular. The output of the first filter will act as input to the second one, and so on.